# conditional statements in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (number n)
(cond
  [(< n 10) 5.0] 
  [(< n 20) 5] 
  [(< n 30) true]))
```

How would I add an else statement at the end?

```
[else false])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
(define (number n)
  (cond
    [(< n 10) 5.0] 
    [(< n 20) 5] 
    [(< n 30) true]
    [else false]))
```

Just remember - the `else` clause (if present) must be the last clause in a `cond` form. If it was not explicitly written and none of the conditions hold, then `#<void>` is returned.

Comment: I added the else statement at the end, not sure why I was getting an error earlier. thanks

Comment: Haha, I just got a message that my post is a duplicate. Turns out I typed in the exact message letter for letter :D